# Unable to decrypt Java's cypher encryption stored in mysql 8

Tags: java, mysql

I have mysql 8.0 database (collation utf-08).
Having Table tbl_test (collation utf-08.) with following field.

id     int               auto_increament
text   varbarinary(100)

I have following values stored using [Java's encrytion library](https://github.com/epayco/epayco-android/blob/master/epayco/src/main/java/co/epayco/android/util/EpaycoCrypt.java)

> 93e4431a51f1cdfd31e970e3e035b3d6

I am trying to decrypt using mysql 8.0. Here is my query

```
set @k = 'bisp123456pitbas';
set @iv = '7654gabasyd854f1';
SELECT id, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(text, @k, @iv) AS CHAR (150)) FROM tbl_test;
```

But always get empty result. It works in mysql 5.7.

Is there anyone can help me on this?

Looking forward.

Comment: You obtained the ciphertext how exactly? with what code?

Comment: Link of code i have shared with title "Java's encrytion library". click on it. You'll get the code. I used that library to encrypt  as 
String encrypted = MCrypt.bytesToHex( mcrypt.encrypt("Kaleemullah") );